# Dropwizard views: add ViewBundle

Tags: dropwizard

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/views/#manual-views) to create DropWizard views. However, when I try to `addBundle(new ViewBundle())`, it fails to find (or import) ViewBundle. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dependency `dropwizard-views` was missing in my maven pom file. Adding the dependency solved the issue.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-views</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to choose one of the view template. As of writing, Dropwizard supports FreeMarker and Mustache. Instead of including `dropwizard-view` dependency, you should choose either `dropwizard-views-mustache` or `dropwizard-views-freemarker`, and `dropwizard-view` will be included as dependency.